# How to read metadata from an avro file in scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, avro

> I want to read the avro schema from the metadata of an avro file in scala. I can do it python, but I don't know how to achieve the same in scala. Below is the python code for the same:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    file_reader = reader(f)
    data = [rec for rec in file_reader]
    avro_schema = file_reader.metadata['avro.schema']
    avro_schema = ast.literal_eval(avro_schema)
```

> Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to do it in plain scala or using spark ?

Comment: @Vincent In spark I can do it using dataframe. I want to do it in plain scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}

val datumReader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord]
val dataFileReader = new DataFileReader[GenericRecord](new File("file.avro"), datumReader)
val schema = dataFileReader.getSchema
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks  @Nir Hedvat, it worked. I am able to get the schema from the avro file now. I have one more question, what if instead of the schema I want to read the metadata of the avro file, how should I do that then ?

Comment: Can you rate me on the question please? What more would you like to get from the file?

Comment: With your solution I am able to read the schema which is a part of avro metadata. Is there any way to read the metadata of avro file ?

Comment: What kind of metadata are you looking for? Num of records?

Comment: Yes num of records

Comment: Use this project: https://github.com/jwoschitz/avrocount/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jwoschitz/avro/tool/AvroCountTool.java . Take a look at the run() method, ignore the parallelism part. Lines 140-146 and 158-160. Each 'inStream' is an Avro file

Comment: Thanks @ Nir Hedvat :)